# respond_to で html と json で返すデータの共有方法を知りたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

indexページにそれぞれの値のデータと、d3jsを使ってグラフを表示させようとしているのですが、以下のように書くと
ページ表示のときと、グラフ描画の際にjsonを読み込むときの２回に渡って
@fooというデータを作るための処理を行ってしまいます。
htmlを表示した段階で@fooにデータはできているのでそれをそのままグラフ描画のために使うにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

```
def index
  @hoge = ...
  @foo = @hoge....
  respond_to do |format|
　　 format.html
　　 format.json {render :json => @foo }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

まず**基本的には**1回のリクエストに対しては1回の応答しか出来ません。

1. HTMLページのリクエストに対して `@foo` を作成してHTMLを応答(index)
2. ブラウザが ajax を使って JSON を要求しそれを応答(index とは別の物である必要があります)

という2回のリクエストおよびレスポンスが必要です。例えば[ここ](http://karur4n.hatenablog.com/entry/sinatra-jquery-de-ajax)にある様に、エンドポイントは2つ必要です。
どうしても

- HTML でも @foo の中身を表示したい
- JSON でも @foo を返したい

という事であれば、この2回のリクエストに対して @foo を作る処理を1回にする為に揮発性のキャッシュを使うのが良いと思います。一定時間だけメモリに保持するといった物です。

もしくは HTML も @foo の中身を表示するのであれば、ajax をやめてしまうのも一つの方法です。

Comment: 逆にAjaxで取ってきたデータで表も生成してしまう手もありますね。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。sessionを使って意図したかった動作ができました！ですが、sessionってこんな時に使っていいものなんですかねー？

Comment: 一応RailsのセッションってユーザーIDやflash程度にとどめるのが推奨されてるみたいですね。。。